# Find all prime p such that Legendre symbol of $\left(\frac{10}{p}\right)$ =1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, jacobi-symbol

In the given question I have been able to break down $\left(\frac{10}{p}\right)$=
$\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$ $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$. But what needs to be done further to obtain the answer.

Comment: Use the formula $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod p$ for $p$ an uneven prime and then consider cases $p\equiv 1$ or $3\mod 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

By the second supplementary law of quadratic reciprocity,$\biggl(\dfrac 2p\biggr)=1$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\mod 8$.

On the other hand, $\biggl(\dfrac 5p\biggr)=\biggl(\dfrac p5\biggr)=1\;$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\mod 5$.

So you have to solve the systems of congruences:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
p\equiv \pm 1\mod8\\p\equiv\pm 1\mod 5
\end{cases}&&
\begin{cases}
p\equiv \pm3\mod8\\p\equiv\pm 2\mod 5
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

This is done  with the *Chinese remainder theorem*. I'll show for one, say $p\equiv 3\mod 8,\;p\equiv 2\mod 5$: start from the *Bézout's relation* $\:2\cdot 8-3\cdot 5=1$. The solutions are then
$$p\equiv 3\cdot (2\cdot 8)-2\cdot(3\cdot 5)\equiv18\mod 40.$$
There is no prime number in this congruence class.

Comment: could you briefly explain why $(5/p) = 1$ iff $p \equiv 1, -1$ mod $5$ ?

Comment: @mathmajor: This is simply because it is equal to $\bigl(\frac p5\bigr)$ (by quadratic reciprocity) and the only non-zero  squares modulo $5$ are $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be an odd prime $\ne 5$.

Note that $(2/p)=1$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$, and $(5/p)=1$ if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$. The first is a standard fact that has probably been proved in your book/course. The second can be proved using Quadratic Reciprocity.

So $(10/p)=1$ if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$ **and** $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$.

But also $(10/p)=1$ if $(2/p)=-1$ and $(5/p)=-1$. This is the case if $p\equiv \pm 3\pmod{8}$ **and** $p\equiv \pm 3\pmod{5}$.

Our conditions can be "simplified" by expressing them modulo $40$.
After some work, we find that the odd prime $p$ satisfies our conditions if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{40}$, $\pm 3\pmod{40}$, $\pm 9\pmod{40}$, or $\pm 13\pmod{40}$.